# When I use the Variable it gets set to 0, why?

Tags: android

When I use the variables gv.PanX and gv.PanY they get reset to 0 why?

The class where I use them (edit them):

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;
            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;


        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        gv.PanX = (int)mPosX;
        gv.PanY = (int)mPosY;
        DragX = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        DragY = ev.getY(pointerIndex);
        break;

    }
```

Where I read them:

```
public void drawbitmapOnCanvas(String bmname, Bitmap bm, int X, int Y, SpriteBatcher sb){
    Log.v("touch", "drawing: " + gv.PanX + " : " + gv.PanY);
    int bmInt = getBitmapInt(bmname);
    int YPan = 0;
    int XPan = 0;

    Rect rec1 = new Rect(0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());

    Rect rec2 = new Rect(XPan + X, YPan + Y, XPan + X + bm.getWidth(), YPan + Y + bm.getHeight());
    sb.draw(bmInt, rec1, rec2);
}
```

The actual variables:

```
public class GlobVar {
public int PanX, PanY = 0;
}
```

and gv stands for this:

```
GlobVar gv = new GlobVar();
```

When ever I don't use the vars and just post them to the Log they work fine but when I try to use them they to go 0 again.
Thanks for everyone that looks at this ;)

Comment: Which value and data type do `mPosX` and `mPosY` have?

Comment: @eightx2 it's as you can see a int, it shows fine when I dont use it but when I do it returns 0

Comment: They won't magically be reset to 0. Do you maybe allocate a new `GlobVar` object?